# How to deal with rejection email replied by apple?

Tags: iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

The rejection email said:

> If you have any questions about this information, or would like to discuss it further, please feel free to reply to this email.

Yes, I want to discuss the problem and submit my modified app again, but I just want to know if the new reviewer is not the one that rejected my app before, the emal I reply to apple will make any effect?
What's the proper way that I should go?

Answer (score 2):

The email should have given you specific reasons why the app was rejected. If there was a crash, they would have given you the exact steps to take to reproduce the crash.

If your app does not comply with the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/XHIGIntro.html), you just need to go back and either re-read them, or fix what they say.

Either way, as long as you comply with Apple's guidelines, you should be Ok.

Your question is very vague, maybe you can provide more details of the email?

All you have to do is fix what the email explains is wrong, and re-submit. I seriously doubt the same reviewer will re-review your app, as your app is put into a queue, and whoever is available for the next in line I'm sure takes the review.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I just re-submit my fixed app without replying to the rejection email ?

Comment: What does the rest of the email say? If it has to do with the Interface Guidelines, or a crash, then No, you do not have to respond if you dont want to. Apple does however have Professionals that you can contact to help you with code and stuff, but I dont think it's free.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to be afraid off.In the Rejection email , they mention the reason why the app was rejected.Most of the cases its the use of private api.

Answer (score 0):

If you uploaded your binary again, you don't need to reply to the mail. But if you want to reply just include the mail of the "first" reviewer and you're on the right way!